# primefaces commandbutton in dialog doesn't work

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Here's my .xhtml:

```
    <h:form id="form_edit"  prependId="false">
        <p:commandButton value="#{filt.add}"
                         ajax="true" 
                         icon="ui-icon-plus"
                         update=":messages :form_edit"
                         oncomplete="confDlg.show()"
                         action="#{agentsbean.clearSelectedAgent()}"/>
    </h:form>
    <p:dialog id="dialogId" widgetVar="confDlg" showEffect="fold" hideEffect="fade" 
              appendToBody="false">
        <h:form>
            <p:inputText value="#{agentsbean.selectedAgent.name==null?'null':agentsbean.selectedAgent.name}"/>
            <p:commandButton id="agConfirmSave" value="#{filt.save}" update=":messages @form"
                             actionListener="#{agentsbean.saveAgent}" oncomplete="confDlg.hide();"/>

        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

actionListener saveAgent :

```
public void saveAgent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    System.out.println("SaveAgent");
}
```

When i click button (agConfirmSave) - dialog close, but action does not start!

- primmefaces 3.5
- Apache 7.0.35

**UPD**
action work, if remove p:inputText or chang it by h:outputText!!! But i need input same text in dialog...

Comment: not sure what's going on , but try to set the appendToBody to `true` , like this : `appendToBody="true"`

Comment: What you want do here with @form: update=":messages @form"?

Comment: with appendToBody="true" same problem

Comment: try remove appendToBody and remove from update @form. You get any error?

Comment: @Darka, in another version of this code update same components. without `update=":messages @form"` action does not start

Comment: first button action clearSelectedAgent works?

Comment: @Darka, yes, action clearSelectedAgent work

Comment: what if you test like this?     <p:dialog id="dialogId" widgetVar="confDlg" >
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton id="agConfirmSave" value="TRY"  actionListener="#{agentsbean.saveAgent}"/>

        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>

Comment: action work, if remove p:inputText or chang it by h:outputText!!! But i need input same text in dialog...

Comment: You try process="@this" to commandButton.

Comment: or try changing this part #{agentsbean.selectedAgent.name==null?'null':agentsbean.selectedAgent.name}

Comment: Wow, i guess the problem is: <p:inputText value="#{agentsbean.selectedAgent.name==null?'null':agentsbean.selectedAgent.name}"/>.

Comment: Yes!!!! Problem with expression!! When <p:inputText value="#{agentsbean.selectedAgent.name}"/> action works!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a valid value expression for a "setter" operation.

```
<p:inputText value="#{agentsbean.selectedAgent.name==null?'null':agentsbean.selectedAgent.name}"/>
```

If you have paid as being a real developer a bit more attention and love to the server logs and HTTP traffic monitor, then you should have noticed an `ELException`/`PropertyNotWritableException` which is basially already the whole answer at its own.

As to how to fix it; the whole expression makes actually no sense at its own. EL is already null-safe. Get rid of the unnecessary conditional check:

```
<p:inputText value="#{agentsbean.selectedAgent.name}"/>
```

Comment: so you say we can't put expression in VALUE?

Comment: @Darka: I have no idea what you're trying to ask. Feel free to test/experiment with it youself, so that you can see the exception yourself.

Comment: I mean, can we use any expression in Value attribute, example: <p:inputText value="#{agentsbean.name eq 'TOM' ? 'TOM B': agentsbean.name}" />. Am I clear now?

Comment: @Darka: that's already been answered. That's not a valid value expression for a "setter" operation. If you still don't get it, experiment yourself in order to see it with own eyes. Own experience is the best answer ever.

Comment: I had this problem before too. I find out it by my self. Just have some questions :) You are right, that you can learn by trying (that's why I read stackoverflow ;) ). Thanks for helping.